# Нужны ли запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Бойцам СО запрещено, ***без разрешения командования***, участвовать в спец.операциях <>. Ставится ли запятая, если ставится, то почему, если не ставится, то тоже — почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, это факультативное обособление. Если автор обособил, значит, это пояснение: участие запрещено, но только без разрешения командования.

Фраза без пояснительного оборота более категорична:
*Бойцам СО запрещено без разрешения командования участвовать в спец.операциях*.

На выбор автора.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, запятые здесь - грубая ошибка. Нет причин для обособления.